# Cypress get button within subject

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have a case where I need to test buttons that are generated through activity on the site (making a game creates a button on their homepage). These buttons should take the user to their game portal.

The buttons are contained within .sidebar--button subject, they are listed from top to bottom.

First I attempted to click the nth button in .sidebar--button by using:

```
    it('selects the 3rd game in the sidebar', () => {
    cy.get('.sidebar--button').eq(2).click()
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.url()
        .should('include', 'portal')
```

This failed as I cannot use .eq to click an element.

Then I tried to use .within to select a single generated button within the .sidebar--button using:

```
it('deletes the current game', () => {
    cy.get('.sidebar--button').should('have.length', 1)
    cy.get('.sidebar--button').within((".sidebar--button") => {
        cy.get('.button').click()
    })
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.url()
        .should('include', 'portal')
```

This failed as well.

How can I cy.get('nth button').click() with only the buttons contained within .sidebar--button ?

Comment: It's worth noting that `.eq(1)` would have worked, as `.eq(1)` will get the 2nd element. The first would have been `.eq(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for that css selectors. For example if you have scenario like this `.parent>.child*4>button` you can access to third element by `.parent:nth-child(3) button`. for more exact css selector i have to know the html structure.

----- Edited -----

Working selector for this case `.sidebar--button:nth-child(3) .button`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Specifically,
 cy.get('.sidebar--button:nth-child(3) .button).click()
will click the 3rd button inside a parent subject.
Thanks much!

Comment: Glad to help. I added your selector to answer to be more visible for others.

Answer (score 4):

Does this button has different text? if yes, then use

```
cy.get('.sidebar--button').contains('whatever the text is').click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. They only contain images.

Comment: For future viewers, this solution worked perfectly for me for a button with a div child that had the text